# Postgresql log user or role changes activity

Tags: postgresql, logging

I need to log all changes(example: granting superuser to user) in user and role, log adding new user/roles, log dropping the user/role. This is regarding to monitor the security of our data and ensure user/roles changes are logged into table or even in log file.

I tried by creating a trigger on `pg_roles` and `pg_user`

```
CREATE TRIGGER pg_roles_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON pg_roles
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_access_log_trigger();
```

But I got error `Error:"pg_roles" is a view. DETAIL:  Views cannot have row-level BEFORE or AFTER triggers`

So tried to create a trigger on base table `pg_authid`. but it also gave error:
`ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_authid" is a system catalog SQL state: 42501`

Is there any option in Postgresql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official postgres docs are helpful here. You can configure `postgresql.conf` to log all queries and ddl by configuring `log_statement` key in the file to `all`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT

If it needs to be loaded into a table you can parse the logs and write that information back into a table or just rotate and back up the logs for when they need to be audited.

Comment: log_statement=all is logging all queries, will cause log file grow bigger.

log_statement=ddl also logging user changes. I think this is better if only user changes are required to log

Comment: If space is an issue you can rotate and archive the logs. Alternatively if the logs aren't needed you can also parse the logs for relevant queries, write them out to a separate log audit file and delete the old logs. These can also be used to load into a postgres table. The ddl option may not cover `grant` clauses.